# What’s the difference between an ordered pair and an ordered set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am told relations are (sets of?) ordered pairs. How do these relate to ordered sets? Are ordered sets ordered by ordered pairs (i.e., relations)?

Comment: What do you mean by an ordered set? A set partially ordered by inclusion or an cartesian product of more than two sets?

Comment: The former, I think.

Comment: An ordered set is simply a set on which an order relation has been defined. There is (conceptually) no difference between the underlying set and any other set (including one consisting of ordered pairs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordered pair and an "ordered set" are mostly distinct ideas, although one is built off the other. An ordered set isn't a thing (as far as I know). There are **well ordered**, **partially ordered**, **totally ordered**, and **linearly ordered** sets. Each of these is a relation defined on the set satisfying certain properties.

For example a total order must be reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric, and strongly connected.

Now a **relation** $R$ on a set $A$ is defined simply as any subset of the product set $A\times A$, which is turn is defined as $A\times A := \{(a,b):a,b \in A\}$ i.e. all of the ordered pairs with elements from your set. Taking some relation $R\subseteq A\times A$, we say for two elements $x,y\in A$, that $x$ is related to $y$, and write $xRy$ or $R(x,y)$ if the ordered pair $(x,y)$ is inside our relation $R$. We are assuming nothing about this relation $R$.

Revisiting ordered sets, these are sets equipped with some special type of relation. For example a partially ordered set $\mathcal{P}$ is a tuple (ordered pair) $\mathcal{P}=(P,\le)$ where $\le$ is a relation as defined above (yes! its a set!) with certain properties, namely a reflexive, antisymmetric, and  transitive.

It's worth noting also that while the types orderings mentioned above are only defined on the cartesian product of a set with itself, relations and ordered pairs or tuples, can be defined on the cartesian product of any sets, and any number of sets. The number of sets in the product is called the *arity* of the relation. For example you can have a relation $R\subseteq \mathbb{R}\times \{0,1\} \times \{a,b,c\} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

To summarize, an ordered pair is a a tuple with two elements where we care about which one is where, and a (partially/totally/linearly/well) ordered set is a set equipped with a relation satisfying some important qualities, sometimes written as an ordered pair.

Finally if you are interested, the formal definition of an ordered pair is
$$(a,b):=\big\{  \{a\},\ \{a,b\} \big\}$$
making the formal definition of the cartesian product of two sets
$$A\times B:= \Big\{ \big\{  \{a\},\ \{a,b\} \big\}\ :\ a\in A,\ b\in B \Big\}$$
altho this definition is mostly used for formalism, and never in day to day math. I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: A beautiful answer—thank you.

Comment: @inkd glad I can be of help :) can you mark mine or MJD's as the accepted answer so the question will be closed?

Answer (score 1):

An ordered set is usually understood to be a set equipped with a partial order. That is, it is a pair of the form $(S, \leq)$ where $S$ is a set and $\leq$ is a *partial order* on $S$: a binary relation on $S$ that is

- Reflexive: $x \leq x$
- Antisymmetric: if $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$, then $x=y$
- Transitive: if $x \leq y$ and $y \leq z$, then $x\leq z$

Since $\leq$ is a binary relation on $S$, it can ultimately be understood as a set of ordered pairs satisfying the above conditions. However, the notion of an ordered pair does not really have much to do with that of an ordered set.

It's probably better to think of an ordered set as a set with additional structure, in this case a partial order. Thus we similarly speak of ordered groups, ordered vector spaces etc..

Answer (score 1):

Ordered sets and ordered pairs are conceptually quite different.

#### Sets, orderings, and pairs

A “set” is a collection of objects with a common property.

An “ordering” is a notion of comparing two objects and deciding that one is “less than” another, or “comes before” another, or some other comparative property.  What the property actually is depends on the context: it depends on what the objects are and on what problem we are trying to solve.  The objects might be numbers and the ordering might be the usual less-than ordering, or the objects might be people and the ordering might be that person $A$ is a descendant of person $B$.  Or the objects might be dinner menus and the ordering is that menu $A$ is more expensive than menu $B$.  An *ordered set* is a set on which an ordering has been defined.

An “ordered pair” is an abstract mathematical object that has two components, and a notion that one of the components is first and the other is second.  The pair whose first component is $x$ and whose second component is $y$ is often written with some notation like $\langle x,y\rangle$, and crucially, this pair is considered *different* from the pair $\langle y,x\rangle$, because in one pair the first component is $x$ and in the other the first component is $y$.

We *could* think of an ordered pair as a sort of ordered set, but it's not usually useful to do so.  An ordered pair is usually considered to be a more primitive sort of object than an ordered set.  We use ordered pairs to define ordered sets, rather than the other way around.

#### Sets as models of other objects

In mathematics, set theory has been so extremely useful for describing mathematical objects that we often like to model mathematical concepts as sets when we can.  Having done this we can write clear definitions of those concepts in terms of set theory, which is widely understood.  We can discuss those concepts using the language of set theory, and learn things about their behavior using theorems of set theory.  We often do use this modeling process with orderings and with ordered pairs.

For example, an ordered pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ can be modeled as a set in several ways.  One model is to think of it as an abbreviation for the set $\{\{x, 1\}, \{y, 2\}\}$.  Another model is to think of it as an abbreviation for the set $\{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$.  But *usually* when we deal with ordered pairs we don't care about the details of this sort of model.  We usually think of the ordered pair $\langle x, y\rangle$ as an abstract object whose first component is $x$ and whose second component is $y$ and leave it at that.  That fact that a pair *can* be modeled as a set is more important than the particular model that we choose.  The details of the model don't normally matter.

Similarly, an ordering can be modeled as a set.  Usually we choose to model an ordering as a set of pairs, one which  includes the pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ exactly when the object $x$ is considered “less than” $y$  or when $x$ “comes before” $y$ in the ordering we are considering.

Since we're thinking of an ordering as a set of pairs, and of a pair as another sort of set, maybe one like $\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$, we *could* think of an ordering as a set of sets.  We do not normally do this.  We model the pairs, and then proceed to ignore or even forget about the model; then we use the pairs to model the ordering.

(We often go even further and model an *ordered set* as a *pair* whose first component is the set and whose second component is the ordering we want to impose on it, itself modeled as a set of pairs.  But again, we almost never think about the objects this way, as sets of sets of sets of sets.  We *could* write out the set of sets of sets of sets that models a particular ordered set, but nobody ever does this except maybe as a curiosity.)

#### The map is not the territory

Some mathematicians are so steeped in set theory that they sometimes forget that the sets are just models, and they will insist that an ordered pair *is* a certain set. But I think my description above is closer to the way most mathematicians really think about pairs: the set is just a model, pairs could be modeled by sets in many different ways, and the details usually don't  matter.  What matters about an ordered pair is that you can tell what the components are and which is first.

I think that hits all your questions.